# Error when building OpenCV in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

I am trying to build OpenCV in Ubuntu 14.04. I use the following cmake command:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 -D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 -D WITH_CUBLAS=1 -D CUDA_ARCH_BIN="2.0 3.0 3.5" ..
```

Which returns the following error:

```
[ 18%] Built target opencv_ts
Linking CXX executable ../../../bin/opencv_test_cudev
/usr/bin/ld: ../../../lib/libopencv_core.so.3.0.0: undefined reference to symbol '__cxa_free_exception@@CXXABI_1.3'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_test_cudev] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/cudev/test/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_cudev.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

A lot of searching on the Internet have not resolved my problem and due to my sparse experience with Ubuntu I am stuck. Any one who can help?